# How do I retrieve text from an input checkbox with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to retrieve the text for selected check boxes like so:

HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox">        
    <input type="checkbox" name="priority" value="2" checked="checked">2 - Critical
</label>
<label class="checkbox">        
    <input type="checkbox" name="priority" value="3">3 - Important
</label>
```

jquery:

```
$('#priorityContents input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    if(priorityText.length > 0) {
        priorityText = priorityText + "|";
    }
    priorityText = priorityText + $(this).text();
});

alert(priorityText);
```

I would expect to see:

```
2 - Critical
```

I don't get any errors in my console. What am I missing?

Comment: your mark up is not valid - the inputs are never closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get to the `label` element, which is the parent of the `input`:

```
$('#priorityContents input[type="checkbox"]:checked').parent();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hk63N/

---

For increased performance, you should consider splitting up the selector:

```
var priorityText = '';

$('#priorityContents input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').parent().each(function() {
    if ( ! priorityText ) {
        priorityText = priorityText + "|";
    }
    priorityText = priorityText + $(this).text();
});

alert(priorityText);​
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/):

> To achieve the best performance when using these selectors, first select some elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter().

Here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hk63N/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="priority" value="2" checked="checked">
<label for='cb' class="checkbox"> 2 - Critical</label>
```

```
$('#priorityContents input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).next('label').text();
});
```

please note that `:checkbox` selector is *deprecated* you can use `input[type="checkbox"]` instead.

Comment: @JosephSilber as I can't remember why I think so, I remove that part.

Comment: There seem to be differing documentation on whether the label tags should go around the input or not. I see no reason why they should, since the `for=` attribute is there to connect it to an input element.

Comment: @JosephSilber _Any form starts with a form element, inside which are placed the controls. Most controls are represented by the input element, which by default provides a one-line text field. To label a control, the label element is used; the label text and the control itself go inside the label element. Each part of a form is considered a paragraph, and is typically separated from other parts using p elements._

Comment: @Raminson - Which is exactly my point. It is perfectly valid for the `input` to be inside the `label`. That said, your code is wrong for a different reason; there's no relation between the `input` and the `label`.

Comment: @Raminson - The only way to associate the `input` to the `label` is by giving the `input` and ID, and then giving the `label` a matching `for` attribute. Since I despise IDs littering my code, I prefer to just wrap my `label`s around the `input`s, as the OP does.

Comment: @Raminson - I've removed my -1, but I still disagree with this answer. You shouldn't be altering the OP's HTML code if it's perfectly valid, and can achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, why would you expect to see that result? At no point in that code have you attempted to retrieve the text. I'd suggest:

```
$('#priorityContents input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    var next = this.nextSibling,
        text = next.nodeType == 3 ? next.nodeValue : '';
    console.log(text);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZNfmu/1/).

This iterates over each checked checkbox within the element of the given `id`, looks at the next sibling of the current node (not the jQuery object, the plain DOM node) and, if that node is a `textNode` (a node of `nodeType` equal to `3`) assigns the `nodeValue` (the text contents of that node) to the variable.

If it's not a `textNode`, then it assigns an empty string instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap the text only in the `<label>` tags, which is a good idea anyway for usability. Assign the `for` attribute  to the ID of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="priority" id="priority-2" value="2" checked="checked">
<label class="checkbox" for="priority-2">        2 - Critical</label>
```

Then you can target this easily with jQuery selectors:

```
$('#priorityContents input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    priorityText = $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').text();
    ...
});
```

That said, the easiest approach might instead be to add whatever text you want in a `data-prioritytext` attribute on the checkbox, and extract that with `.data('prioritytext')` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's some stuff definitely missing from your code.  Like the #priorityContents elements which is pretty important if you're searching for it.

Anyway I created this demo that works for me.  Basically what you have wrong I believe is this part:

```
priorityText = priorityText + $(this).text();
```

The actual checkbox element doesn't own the .text().  YOu needt to go up to the parent to get the actual value contained in there.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G7FcC/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var checkedTxt=$('.checkbox :checked').parent().text();
console.log(checkedTxt);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ZZgWa/1/)

Answer (score -1):

`var name=$(this).parent().text();`

you will get the  text of that checkbox
 In html checkbox have no attributes to take text data. so 
use  `parent()`function to take

Answer (score -1):

you can retrieve text of checked checkbox this way using jquery.

```
var value = $(document).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('value');
```